# Converting VLC to FMX MoveTo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Currently the VCL has

```
 WITH Canvas DO
          BEGIN
            CASE PathStyle OF

          psLine:
            BEGIN
                strokeThickness := Max(1, MulDiv( Min(xCellSize,yCellSize), 2, 10));
                MoveTo(xOffset + PosX * xCellSize + xCellSize DIV 2,yOffset + PosY * yCellSize + yCellSize DIV 2);
             END
```

But i get error on moveto (undefined).

So how can i convert the moveto to work with FMX?

Comment: now that i see it it is a TCanvas.moveto  Sorry did not notice it before , thus i think the TPathStyle is ok and should NOT be TPathData.  Thus real question is how to make TCanvas.MoveTo to fmx...now to edit question..once again sorry , never used moveto and did not notice the canvas with/do  statement

Comment: Read the documentation and the examples. It's all there on the docwiki.

Comment: Would that not be the answer to all delphi questions?

Comment: How do you think I work out my answers?

Comment: 212000 + rep from a one liner!  btw i have tried drawline but it says incompatible types TPointF and integer... so i assumed that was not it..but maybe i am wrong?

Comment: Pass the right type to the function. Read the docs and the samples.

Comment: The answer is here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types.TCanvas.DrawLine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The separate MoveTo and LineTo methods do not translate literally. Instead you make a single call to the [DrawLine](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types.TCanvas.DrawLine) method of TCanvas. This receives two TPointF parameters that specify the beginning and end of the line segment. As well you pass an opacity parameter, 100 for opaque.

Borrowing from the [official samples](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/FMXTCanvasDrawFunctions_%28Delphi%29):

```
var
  p1, p2: TPointF;
begin
  // sets the ends of the line to be drawn
  p1.Create(20, 2);
  p2.Create(350, 400);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  // draw the line on the canvas
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p1, p2, 100);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  // updates the bitmap
  Image1.Bitmap.BitmapChanged;
end;
```

---

For what it is worth, the TPointF type is one of the worst designed types I've seen in a long while. Its faults are multitudinous:

- No static class method returning a new value. This forces you to declare variables just to make a simple call to DrawLine as in the code above.
- Dreadfully named initializing functions named Create that make you think this is a class rather than a record.
- Pointless arithmetic methods in addition to the overloaded operators.
- Pointless mutating methods like Offset for functionality that is best expressed with operators.

Comment: why in draw line is there two points?  P1 and P2  i took it as draw line ( x,y )  of end point,  thus DrawLine(P1.x, P1.y, 1)  No p2?

Comment: That is explained both in my answer, and the documentation I linked to. Rather than me writing it again, could you perhaps take one more read of what I wrote.

Comment: yea i understood what you said, just thought it was different. anyhow after removing both move to and line to and replaceing it with this , it now works, Thanks